# Dynamically updating a comboBox from resource folder.(C# WF or WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, resources

I have a resource folder added to my project which is full of csv files. What i essentially want to do is "bind" a comboBox with the names of the files in the resource folder. IF i add a new csv file to the Resource folder, the name should be displayed in the comboBox and if i delete one from the folder then it should be deleted from the comboBox too. How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) . You can detect changes such as new files, deletions, and edits. I would create an ObservableCollection and get the file listing and put the names in the ObservableCollection. Then setup the FileSystemWatcher to notify you of changes and you can modify your ObservableCollection. Then just bind the ComboBox to the ObservableCollection.